# RestSharp v. WebClient?

Tags: silverlight, rest, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm building a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app. Is there any reason to use RestSharp instead of WebClient? I've looked around on the RestSharp site, but it's not immediately obvious what the benefits are.

Comment: The reader may take a look at [differences between RestSharp and ServiceStack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117376/) where the lead of service stack and user Runscope API Tools - the former lead of restsharp [1](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/my-net-open-source-project-management-nightmare), [2](http://haacked.com/archive/2013/09/18/restsharp-104-2-0-released.aspx) - give a recommendation about these two options.

Comment: The article http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/ recommends HttpClient for .Net 4.5+

Answer (score 21):

RestSharp removes the following pain points:

- Quirks in .NET's HTTP classes (basic authentication is broken, error handling for non-200 responses, etc)
- Automatic deserialization from response data to POCOs
- Simplified API (`request.AddParameter(name, value)` instead of manually compiling request bodies
- Simplified request/response semantics, especially for async (however, it's opinionated for async and may not meet everyone's needs, in which case I would also suggest evaluating [Hammock](http://hammock.codeplex.com))

Deserialization is probably the biggest gain since for most APIs you don't have to do very much to get the XML or JSON into your C# objects.

I would check out these pages for more info

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/RestSharp-Blog-Posts-and-Links

Feel free to post any questions here or on the [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp)

Comment: These links are dead. Any chance you can update them?

Comment: Hi John, please confirm, can Restsharp be used in windows service? Or WinHttp the only option?