# How can I convert this .NET RestSharp code to Microsoft.Net.Http HttpClient code?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to figure out how to use `HttpClient` to `POST` some simple parameters.

- Email
- Password

I've been doing this with RestSharp, but I'm trying to migrate off that.

**How can I do this with `HttpClient`, please?**

I have the following RestSharp code

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest("account/authenticate", Method.POST);
restRequest.AddParameter("Email", email);
restRequest.AddParameter("Password", password);
```

How can I convert that to use the `(Microsoft.Net.Http) HttpClient` class, instead?

Take note: I'm doing a POST

Also, this is with the PCL assembly.

Lastly, can I add in a custom header. Say: `"ILikeTurtles", "true"`.

Comment: Both of your questions have been answered before, see [.NET HttpClient. How to POST string value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value) and [Adding Http Headers to HttpClient (ASP.NET Web API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient-asp-net-web-api). Try to use the search.

Comment: ... hold on a second here.  Are there really **three** `HttpClient` classes now?  `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, `Microsoft.Net.Http.HttpClient` and `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`?  Really, Microsoft?  Really?

Comment: That's a really good question. I've only read about `Microsoft.Net.HttpClient` .. there really are -three- ??

Comment: @Charles There are two.  System.Net.Http.HttpClient which is in the nuget package Microsoft.Net.Http and Windows.Web.HttpClient which is a native implementation.

Comment: @Pure.Krome may i know why you decided to go with  Microsoft.Net.HttpClient instead of RestSharp..The latters syntax seems to be more readable

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan having one less dependency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ILikeTurtles", "true");

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters["Email"] = "myemail";
parameters["Password"] = "password";

var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/", new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not opposed to using a library per se, as long as it's `HttpClient` under the hood, [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http) is another alternative. [disclaimer: I'm the author]

This scenario would look like this:

```
var result = await "http://www.example.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("account/authenticate")
    .WithHeader("ILikeTurtles", "true")
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { Email = email, Password = password });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't using HttpClient but it's using the System.Net.WebClient class, i guess it does the same thing though.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string uri = "http://www.example.com/";
        string email = "email@example.com";
        string password = "secret123";

        var client = new WebClient();

        // Adding custom headers
        client.Headers.Add("ILikeTurtles", "true");

        // Adding values to the querystring
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        query["email"] = email;
        query["password"] = password;
        string queryString = query.ToString();

        // Uploadstring does a POST request to the specified server
        client.UploadString(uri, queryString);
    }
```