# Using ServiceStack JsonServiceClient to call external REST API using GET

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am looking to call an external API using ServiceStack and handle the JSON response. Can someone assist please as I am new to ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

[ServiceStack's C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) are only meant for consuming ServiceStack Services which you can use with your Services C# DTOs to enable an end-to-end Typed API as seen in the stand-alone example on [ServiceStack's Github home page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/#simple-customer-database-rest-services-example).

If you want to consume a non-ServiceStack 3rd Party API it's recommended to instead use ServiceStack's [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) as [mentioned in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118120/85785).