# Specifying to ServiceStack to send a parameter as a query parameter

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm using the JsonHttpClient to communicate to an existing REST server. Is there any way to specify to send certain parameters as Query / form parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We [don't recommend using ServiceStack's Service Clients for 3rd Party APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118120/85785), instead you can use [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) which are more flexible and will let you send queryString with:

```
var url = baseUrl
    .AddQueryParam("foo", 1)
    .AddQueryParam("bar", 2);
```

As well as a number of [different APIs to send HTTP FormData](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#posting-data), e.g:

```
var response = url
    .PostToUrl("Username=mythz&Password=password");

var response = url
    .PostToUrl(new Login { Username="mythz", Password="password" });
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd been hoping to take advantage of the client API - but I guess what I need isn't currently supported. I take it you wouldn't consider implementing this via the Swagger attributes? The issue I have is the API expects a mixture of query parameters and body.

Comment: @user2036256 Not for the Service Clients which are optimized for consuming ServiceStack Services.