# (422) Unprocessable Entity with ServiceStack Routing

Tags: c#, servicestack

I had a plan to connect to a JSON-based API using ServceStack's Routing features for C#. It seems that I get a '422 Unprocessable Entity' when attempting to do so when, in reality I'm supposed to be getting a JSON response. This error message is interesting though, since it repeats itself multiple times over (8 times exact) with the message **Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.** Full stack trace below.

I've tried many configurations, and there is one that 'works' but removes one of the key needs of the way this route is set up. In this project, I use `ICacheClient` to save a session key for 5 minutes, so I don't always need to call the API every time I need it. Since ServiceStack uses injection to set my instance of `ICacheClient`, it must be public. However, if it is public I get that 422 error, but if it isn't public I get a NullPointer because it's reference cannot be set by ServiceStack.

Here's my current setup:

AppHost.cs

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Log.Info("Starting up...");
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // Add Plugins
        // Add Connection Strings
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.RegisterAs<ApiClientWrapper, IApiClient>();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Log.Info("Started in {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

ApiClientWrapper.cs

```
public class ApiClientWrapper : IApiClient
{
    // These are set in a Web.config, and work fine.
    private string Username => HostContext.AppSettings.Get<string>("Username");
    private string Password => HostContext.AppSettings.Get<string>("Password");
    private string ApiUrl => HostContext.AppSettings.Get<string>("ApiUrl");

    // This must be public, NULL if private or internal
    public ICacheClient Cache { get; set; }

    private string GenerateAccessToken()
    {
        const string key = "ApiSessionKey";

        var sessionKey = Cache.Get<string>(key);

        if (sessionKey == null)
        {
            using(var client = new JsonServiceClient(ApiUrl))
            {
                var request = new LoginRequest
                {
                    Username = Username,
                    Password = Password
                };
                // Token provided by API
                sessionKey = client.Post(request).AccessToken;
            }
            Cache.Add(key, sessionKey, 5.Minutes());
        }

        return sessionKey;
    }

    internal JsonServiceClient Api => new JsonServiceClient(ApiUrl)
    {
        BearerToken = $"Bearer {GenerateAccessToken()}"
    };

    public List<Price> FindPrices(FindPrices request)
    {   
        /*
         * LatestPricesResponse DTO matches the expected JSON response.
         * The class has the [DataContract] tag, and each property has the [DataMember] tag.
         */
        var response = Api.Get(new LatestPricesRequest());
        response = request.MaxRows.HasValue ? response.Take(request.MaxRows.Value).ToList() : response;
        return response.ToDto();
    }

    [Route("/login", Verb.Post)]
    [DataContract]
    public class LoginRequest : IReturn<LoginResponse>, IPost
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("/latest_prices", Verb.Get)]
    [DataContract]
    public class LatestPricesRequest : IReturn<List<LatestPricesResponse>>, IGet
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "show_details")]
        public string ShowDetails => "no";
    }
}
```

Full Stacktrace:

```
2020-05-29 15:52:02.5996 ERROR DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ToWebServiceException  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (422) UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\ServiceClientBase.cs:line 1317  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (422) UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\ServiceClientBase.cs:line 1317
2020-05-29 15:52:02.5996 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ToWebServiceException  Status Code : 422  
2020-05-29 15:52:02.5996 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ToWebServiceException  Status Description : UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY  
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6266 ERROR DEVELOPER-PC Api.AppHost.SetHostConfig  An exception was thrown on "GET" for path "/prices"  422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY
Code: UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY, Message: 

2020-05-29 15:52:02.6486 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6486 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6486 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6686 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6686 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6686 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6686 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
2020-05-29 15:52:02.6736 DEBUG DEVELOPER-PC ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus  Could not parse Error ResponseStatus ErrorResponse  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowIndexOutOfRangeException()
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 300
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJsv.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeTypeRefJsv.cs:line 40
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJsv(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeType.cs:line 60
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 102
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvReader.Generic.cs:line 81
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\TypeSerializer.cs:line 67
   at ServiceStack.WebServiceException.get_ResponseStatus() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\WebServiceException.cs:line 70
```

Thanks for taking a look, everyone!

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest [v5.8.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) and check if the issue persists, if it does can you update your question to include the full raw HTTP Response that causes this Exception, using a HTTP Packet Sniffer like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: @myth My ServiceStack version is managed on NuGet, and the latest version provided (including pre-releases) is v5.8.0. In regards to the raw HTTP response, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/VChDXkus).

Comment: To determine if this is still an issue you’d need to [upgrade to v5.8.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) where issues similar to this have been resolved.

Comment: It looks like this only shows GET HTTP Request, not the raw HTTP Response.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies - I did send the wrong section. [This](https://pastebin.com/UVGGATTN) is the actual HTTP JSON response. Unfortunately, my ServiceStack key (provided by my company) is not compatible with version 5.8.1 of ServiceStack - so updating is not currently an option for me.

Comment: @mythz I re-ran my tests on a new, blank machine and fresh bare-bones settings using OpenApi / SwaggerUI to test my routes. Again, using the same format in v5.8.1 of ServiceStack from MyGet, [the stack trace](https://hastebin.com/xisipoxuwa.css) is still very similar to version 5.8.0. I've deduced that it is something to do with the `Api.Get(new LatestPricesRequest())` line. Without it, I can manually return anything of type `List<LatestPriceResponse>` without an error.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to identify the issue without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) referencing the latest v5.8.1 where the issue is likely resolved. The `Api` makes a remote call, is the remote service it's calling running v5.8.1?

Comment: @mythz In this case, there is nothing remote about this project. It is all ran on a local system, using localhost as my web host. However, it does interact with a JSON-based API from another company that is formatted in a way that should be accessible by ServiceStack Routing. I am unsure if they use ServiceStack v5.8.1. My [minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/NoEffort/ServiceStackRouting/tree/master) should have everything you need, besides redacted URL's and passwords.

Comment: link returns a 404, is it private? First please confirm that the 3rd Party API returns a successful 200 JSON response.

Comment: @mythz Yeah, it was private. You shouldn't get a 404 anymore. I do know that I can get data from that route using ServiceStack.HttpUtils and the `"URL".GetJsonFromUrl()` functionality. It's just strange in this case because my `POST` to log in works but my `GET` to get data from this route does not. I have also used Fiddler 2 to manually send a request to that URL and that worked fine as well.

Comment: If you're using fiddler you should be able to inspect the response from the API request, see how to [configure .NET Applications](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp) so fiddler can capture the internal traffic.

Comment: Also note that Service Clients are only designed & supported for calling ServiceStack Services, to call 3rd Party APIs you should use a generic HTTP Client like [RestSharp or HTTP Utils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118120/85785) or .NET's HttpClient or WebRequest directly.

Comment: @mythz [This](https://pastebin.com/zxseMggC) is a good, 200 OK response. It contains both the request and response. [This](https://pastebin.com/UVGGATTN) is the bad, 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY response. This one only contains the response information. Both are run over HTTPS.
EDIT: Ok, If that's the case there are other ways to do this but Routing seemed to be the most straight-forward at the time.

Comment: The bad response which returns a `WebServiceException` indicates your internal Service Client request fails.

Comment: Right. I'm trying to figure out what happens between my `LoginRequest` and my `Api.Get(...)` request because, as I mentioned, logging in (`POST`) has no issues but that `GET` request causes problems. We know that the way I've constructed the services, client-side routes and interfaces is fine because code from inside `GetPrices(...)` can be run, unless there is a call the `Api` in the method. EDIT: @mythz

Comment: The internal `Api` remote Service Client Request is what's throwing the `WebServiceException`, so something is not OK with it. Given it's not calling a ServiceStack Service it shouldn't be using the Service Clients to call it, if you used a generic HTTP Client to call it manually you would break the request into multiple steps (i.e. download JSON string first, then deserialize it) where you'd better be able to identify what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the following issue:
- The 3rd-party provider automatically adds "Bearer" before your token.

This snippet:

```
    internal JsonServiceClient Api => new JsonServiceClient(ApiUrl)
    {
        BearerToken = $"Bearer {GenerateAccessToken()}"
    };
```

Was changed to:

```
    internal JsonServiceClient Api => new JsonServiceClient(ApiUrl)
    {
        BearerToken = GenerateAccessToken()
    };
```

To solve the problem.
What I was initially generating was "Bearer Bearer (token)", which is why I would get a 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY (sending the wrong data).

Thanks for the help, everyone!